# How does JSF send form component values to another page?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm new to JSF, I'm trying to understand what is the standard way for pages to send parameters between each other.

I have one page with some form elements:

form.xhtml:

```
<h:form>
<p:selectManyButton name="numbers" id="lstNumbers" >
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"></f:selectItem>
</p:selectManyButton>

<br /><br />
<p:selectManyButton name="letters" id="lstLetters" >
    <f:selectItem itemValue="A" itemLabel="A"></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="B" itemLabel="B"></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="C" itemLabel="C"></f:selectItem>
</p:selectManyButton>

<p:commandButton value="Go" action="results">
</p:commandButton>
```

And my results page where I want to get what items were selected from the form.

results.xhtml:

```
<h:body>

<br /><br /> param.numbers: "#{ param.numbers }"
<br /><br /> param.letters: "#{ param.letters }"

</h:body>
```

What am I missing that I cannot get form.xhtml to send the selected items to results.xhtml as parameters (either GET or POST)?

I can get this to work with a flowscoped bean, but that seems overkill for a simple task. Somehow I think I've got the wrong approach to this altogether. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Flow scoped bean is indeed overkill. Why didn't you consider a request scoped bean then? The "How" is already answered by just looking at generated HTML output and HTTP payload.

Comment: I've tried with request scope and view scoped beans. Nothing gets submitted to the next page as parameter. I figure there's a standard way to submit parameters from one page to another that I'm missing. What I'm doing right now is creating a "results.xhtml?numbers=1,2,3" url in the command button's server side action. But I don't know if this is the correct way to do it.